# In zend framework i want to remove white space and new line in my html response

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to compress my html/js code when I get response from front controller in zend or before the content is sent to the client.

When I view this code in `view source` it shows all the code with spaces not like in Google.

is there a way to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) that runs during dispatchLoopShutdown from where you can get the body of the response, manipulate it and then set the body after minifying it.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

class Application_Plugin_ShrinkSource extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopShutdown()
    {
        // get the output that will be sent to the client
        $body = $this->getResponse()->getBody();

        // remove extra whitespace, and other cleanup
        $body = someFunctionToRemoveWhitespace($body)

        // set the modified content back to the body
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($body);
    }
}
```

In your bootstrap you can register the plugin like

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
    ->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_ShrinkSource());
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. It really worked... Great. Can you help me with one more thing. I also want to gzip the data which come after removing the space. How can I do it here,

Comment: I think the code provided in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8566657/892493) is good for it.  Either have Apache do it for you, or check that the browser will accept gzip encoding, and if so send the content-encoding header and gzencode your body.  You should also add a content-length header that contains the length of the gz encoded response.